# Populate an excel object with List entry items

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, excel

I have a requirement that requires generation of an Excel document programmatically in SharePoint. I need to use an Excel template that has labels like

```
Name:
Designation:
Email:
```

I have a list with the same columns. I need to fetch data from this list and populate instances of the aforesaid template and save it.

```
Name : XYZ 
Designation : ABC
Email : 1@a.com
```

This has to be done programmatically. Any idea how I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what did you write so far? 
You could write a solution and let it run maybe on item-created or whatever kind of occurence you want it to happen. Then you need a Excel-Library (Aspose etc.) to create an Excel File. In the SPContext you are able to get List-Items and so you can write them to a Excel-File.

Comment: I can create a excel sheet from scratch and save it just fine. I want to use a preexisting excel sheet, probably stored in a library. Populate a copy of it with list items and save it. That would reduce a lot of unnecessary overheads....

Comment: maybe you want to use this code fragment:   http://www.sharepointwithattitude.com/archives/61 then you could open the document, edit it and then save it in a different location.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to retrieve the excel. All I need to do now is to copy it to another library and populate it :)